# How to iterate through a table on IOS using Java

Tags: java, appium-ios

I need to write a test case for adding a country code based on country name from a dropdown in an iOS app using java

Below is the Country Name and Country Code table. When selecting a country name, the country code gets added to the dropdown. How to iterate through the table and select a country name.

[image]

Comment: Please someone answer.

Comment: Check my answer below and kindly confirm if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach should serve your need.

```
// Find the table.
MobileElement table = driver.findElement (By.className ("XCUIElementTypeTable"));
// Get all the text labels from the table.
List <MobileElement> texts = table.findElements (By.className ("XCUIElementTypeStaticText"));
// Traverse on the list to find the required country.
MobileElement country = texts.stream()
  .filter (e -> e.getText ().equalsIgnoreCase ("Your Country"))
  .findFirst ()
  .get();
// Perform tap on the selected country.
new TouchAction (driver).tap (country).perform ();
```